# Water Vapor content at equilibrium in vacuum

Tags: thermodynamics

Given a hard bodied vacuum sealed container $C$. $C$ itself is internally divided into two sealed sub-containers $C_{lower}$ and $C_{upper}$ (each having volume $V$ $m^3$).

$C_{lower}$ is completely filled with water, whereas $C_{upper}$ contains (assume perfect) vacuum. Assuming the environmental temperature of $T$ degrees Celsius, when we open the separation between both how do we (approximately) calculate the maximum amount of water vapor ($kg/m^3$ at temperature $T$) (at equilibrium)? If needed, we can assume standard atmospheric pressure to keep things simple.

I am aware about the *Absolute Humidity* values for air (https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/maximum-moisture-content-air-d_1403.html) but unclear about this vacuum scenario.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440703

Comment: @KarstenTheis Thank you. Yes agreed its related but that seems to be just a conceptual question. I am unsure how to calculate the actual vapor content from it..

Comment: You’d get the equilibrium vapor pressure for temp T which you can read off of an H2O phase diagram

Comment: As I understand you are referring to this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure_of_water). Just a followup aren't these values for an open system (air at standard 1 atm). Or can I assume these values are for a closed vacuum system (as in Q) and I can use them to calculate the vapor density of above system?

Comment: The vapor pressure determines the temperature T, or vice versa. When you say you can impose "standard atmospheric pressure" the effect is probably not what you think. The relevant pressure is the vapor pressure. See for instance https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138256/change-in-water-vapor-with-change-in-pressure-and-volume?rq=1

Comment: The presence or absence of air does not affect the equilibrium  vapor pressure of H2O. It is solely a function of temp

Comment: The vapor pressure is a function of T and inert gas pressure. this adds a second component to the phase rule.